# Why is this db query returning null instead of a JSONObject?

Tags: php, android

I have a PHP class that retrieves data from a Database and encodes it as a **JSONArray** to use it later in an Android app. For some reason is returning **null** and I have no clue what is wrong with it.

Here is the file:

```
<?php

$response = array();

// include db connect class
require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

// connecting to db
$db = new DB_CONNECT();
$dbh = $db->connect(); // here you get the connection


if(isset($_GET['TAG_ID'])){
$id = $_GET['TAG_ID'];
$query = "SELECT *FROM lost_pets WHERE id = '$id'";

$result = $dbh->prepare($query);
$result->execute();

if ($result->fetchAll() > 0) {


     foreach($dbh->query($query) as $row){
            $pet["name"] = $row['name'];
            $pet["breed"] = $row['breed'];
            $pet["type"] = $row['type'];
            $pet["description"] = $row['description'];
            $pet["pictures"] = $row['pictures'];
            $pet["location"] = $row['location'];
            $pet["locality"] = $row['locality'];
            $pet["userid"] = $row['userid'];


        echo json_encode($result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Android side:

```
else if(method.equals("GET")){
        // request method is GET

        if (sbParams.length() != 0) {
            url += "?" + sbParams.toString();
        }

        try {
            urlObj = new URL(url);
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) urlObj.openConnection();
            conn.setDoOutput(false);
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", charset);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
            conn.connect();
            is = conn.getInputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
            elements = new JSONArray(json);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        return elements;
    }
```

The id is given by the app and I already checked that are possible values.I have a poor understanding of PHP, so probably is not a difficult problem to solve, anyway i hope you can help me with this, thank you!

Comment: What is returning NULL exactly. At `connect() `?

Comment: @niCkcAMel I think $result is returning null

Comment: `SELECT *FROM` -> `SELECT * FROM` - Not entirely sure this is causing issues but.. I think it is

Comment: @niCkcAMel it works if instead of  echo json_encode($result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)); $response["pet"] = array(); i use array_push($response["pet"], $pet);
        echo json_encode($response); But that retrieves a JSONObject and i need a JSONArray...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what really happened here, but deleting that if clause solved the problem. Thanks for all your comments